# insert a function into more than one blueprints in Flask

Tags: python, function, session, flask

I have two blueprints in my flask project

1 account
2 main

however I also have a function to check if there has session exists in user's browser

I need to implement this function to my two blueprints, and it is a global app function

any hint?
now I just insert two times in my two blueprints view .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use decorator.

```
import flask, flask.views
import functools
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def login_required(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'username' in flask.session:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flask.flash("A login is required to see the page!")
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
    return wrapper

class Account(flask.views.MethodView):
    @login_required
```

[Login Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnNHVupZi5c)

He explains how to make the decorators.

Answer (score 0):

`Blueprint` very similar to `Flask` application, you can found `before_request` and etc methods in both. In your case `before_request` look solution. So you can extend blueprint:

```
class MyBlueprint(Blueprint):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.before_request(self.do_something_before_request)

    def do_something_before_request(self):
        pass
```